# CompareTo и object

Tags: c#, сравнение

Здравствуйте. У меня появился такой вопрос: зачем в C# метод CompareTo интерфейса IComparable принимает параметр типа object? Не проще ли принимать параметр того же типа IComparable? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Думаю по той причине, что по ссылке на интерфейс сложно восстановить ссылку на объект. По ссылке на object это точно можно сделать и однозначно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В .NET на самом деле есть оба интерфейса: [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) и [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx). Первый сохраняется как наследие со времён .NET 1.x, в котором не было обобщённых типов (генериков).

Для старого `IComparable` каким может быть тип аргумента функции `CompareTo`? Это должен быть один тип на все возможные случаи использования, для сравнения любого типа с собой, так что единственное, что может в принципе подойти, это `object`.

Для нового `IComparable<T>` мы можем объявить возможность сравнения с любым типом `Т`, которым захотим. Разумеется, никто не помешает написать

```
class A : IComparable<B> { ...
```

— но правильное использование интерфейса, конечно, для сравнения с объектами того же самого типа:

```
class A : IComparable<А> { ...
```

К сожалению, система типов .NET на текущий момент недостаточно сильна, чтобы выразить ограничение «тип, сравнимый с *самим собой*», а не просто «тип, сравнимый с данным типом». Если вам интересны языки с более развитой системой типов, гляньте в сторону функциональных языков.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, система типов языка Haskell имеет возможность выразить такие зависимости. Пусть знатоки функциональных языков поправят меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Вот обсуждение по теме: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8122109/276994

Answer (score 2):

Этого достаточно

Это намного проще с точки зрения дизайна языка.

Например, вы пишите метод сортировки и объявляете его как

```
void Sort<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IComparable
```

тем самым давая возможность сортировать объекты любых сравнимых типов.

Единственный способ сделать строготипизированный интерфейс IComparable, это объявить его как

```
interface IComparable<in T> {
     int CompareTo(T obj);
}
```

Но тогда никто не запретит вам сделать это

```
class Foo : IComparable<Bar>, IComparable<String> {...}
```

Что, согласитесь, совсем не логично.